# vscode Go extension is not showing useful intellisense completions

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, intellisense

On my Ubuntu VM, I recently upgraded vscode, Go, and the vscode Go extension, all to the latest versions (1.60.0, 1.17, 0.27.2).

I started writing some new code, from tutorials in a book.

I'm noticing that Intellisense is only inconsistently showing useful completions on ctrl+space.  In fact, I know I've seen it present useful completions, but now that I'm trying, I can't find a situation where it does it.

The only choices I can get from it are "const", "func", "import", "type", and "var".

The following pictures show examples of this:

[image: attempt completion for filepath]

[image: attempt completion for filepath choices]

[image: attempt completion for Join]

Comment: It happens to me only, when I open a file from another package. Did you open a whole go package (folder) or just one file?

Comment: Is `gopls` installed? `gopls` is the Go language server which provides these features to VS Code and other IDEs. It must be installed in addition to VS Code, Go, and the VS Code Go extension. Normally, the VS Code Go extension will give you an option to install `gopls` automatically.

Comment: I created an empty directory, and I'm adding new files to the directory as I step through the tutorials. gopls is also installed and updated, now at version v0.7.1.

Comment: What tutorials do you use? I saw many users encountered similar issues because tutorials were written before Go Modules were introduced. Do you have `go.mod` file in the root of the workspace?

And, check https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

Comment: Right now, I'm using "Mastering Go", published last month. I did not have a go.mod file. As all of these test scripts have "main" funcs, doesn't that imply that a go.mod file would cause more problems than it solves? I tried creating one, but it complains about multiple "main" funcs. I will examine the troubleshooting page.

Comment: Ok, well, one curious thing is that vscode seems to think it's still in the previous go module that I worked on. I can't seem to convince the explorer to list the scripts in the other directory that I'm working in now.

Comment: I don't know what problems prevent you from having `go.mod` file. That defines the main module you are working on so is necessary. Have a separate directory for each main package. Unfortunately, multiple `main` func in one directory isn't well supported (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41206)

Mastering Go was originally published in 2018, right?

Comment: What I am reading is the third edition, which was published last month. I acknowledge that the practice of having multiple "main" funcs in the same directory is going to create problems.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to check your settings.json and remove `experimentalWorkspaceModule` setting. This setting has been deprecated and seems to be causing the problem you're having.